# using Google Analytics hitCallback to send event before redirection to url

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I tried to trigger an Google Analytics event when a specific link is clicked. To make sure the event is send before redirecting to the url, Google suggests to use the hitCallback function.

I tried it this way, but it won't work, because the link is immediately opened:

```
$('#service a').on("click",function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
  var title = $(this).data('title');
  var url   = $(this).attr('href');

  if ( typeof ga === 'function' ) {
    //console.log('started');
    ga('send', {
      hitType: 'event',
      eventCategory: 'header',
      eventAction: 'nav',
      eventLabel: 'service',
      eventValue: title,
      hitCallback : createFunctionWithTimeout(function() {
         //console.log('done')
         document.location = url;
      }, 100000)
    });
  }else{
    document.location = url;
  }

});
```

[Here is the timeout function](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits), suggested by Google:

```
function createFunctionWithTimeout(callback, opt_timeout) {
  var called = false;
    function fn() {
      if (!called) {
        called = true;
        callback();
      }
    }setTimeout(fn, 1000);
  return fn;
}
```

I would like to know why it isn't working, or if there is another way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Event value should be of integer type. Can you try hardcoding an integer to see if it works?